# How do I get the original url of an embed image? discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I get the original url of an embed's image? When I use this code, I get the https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/ URL

```
let ans = '';    
message.embeds.forEach(embed => {
     ans = embed.image.url
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the image embed pasted as a URL link, or is the image attached? If it's attached, then Discord creates its own URL. If it was pasted as a link, then it should work.

Comment: I think it is attached. Is there a way to get the URL still?

Comment: Why are you tagging `discord.py` if you're using `discord.js`?

Comment: @DeviousDev if it's attached, then it does not have any *original* URL. It's on Discord's server.

Comment: I thought they might be similar since the libraries have many similarities. If there is a solution in discord.py I would switch to that.

Comment: `discord.py` is a library for python, not javascript @DeviousDev